# How to force reload of web page after user has followed links off it?

Tags: html

If you follow a link out of my webpage, how can I ensure the webpage reloads when the user returns?

Especially: if the link loads in a separate window, how can I reload my webpage then?

I am wondering about the approaches, especially any that avoid javascript, and what their pros and cons are.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this kind of problem is to request the browser doesn't cache the page - so that it simply has to reload each time.

The accepted way to do this is with the **Cache-Control** HTTP header, specifically setting it to **no-cache**, however there are a [couple of possibilities](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html) depending on exactly the behaviour you want.

Comment: And to make the page reload when the user follows a link that opens in another window?

Comment: @Will - Then I'm afraid javascript is your only option, any particular reason for avoiding it?

Comment: I was hoping for lateral thinking with refresh headers openning in new windows etc